# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid document reference

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jsx, leaderboard

```
import { getDocs, collection, query, doc, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
import { useState } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebaseConfig";
import { useEffect } from "react";


function EndGame(startGame){
    const {startGameHandler} = startGame;
    const startGameClick = startGameHandler[0];
    const time = startGameHandler[1];
    const [leaderboard, setLeaderboard] = useState([]);    
    const [user, setUser] = useState("");
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
    const [isAnonymous, setIsAnonymous] = useState(false);
   
   const loginAnonymously = () =>{
    console.log("login hivas ", user)
    setUser(username)
    setIsAnonymous(true)
    }
   const setScore= async(timeprop, userprop)=>{
        console.log(time, user)
        await addDoc(doc(db, "Leaderboard"), {
        name: userprop,
        time: timeprop,
      })
    }
        async function getLeaderboard(){
            const q = query(collection(db, "Leaderboard"));
            const chacSnapShot =  await getDocs(q);
            const char = chacSnapShot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
            setLeaderboard(char)
        }
       
   useEffect(()=>{
    setScore(time, user)
    getLeaderboard()
   }, [isAnonymous])
    
    return(
        <div className={`endgame-page`}>

               {!isAnonymous && (
                <div className="endgame-div">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter a username"
                        value={username}
                        onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button onClick={loginAnonymously}>Login Anonymously</button>
                </div>
            )}

            {isAnonymous && (
            <div className="endgame-div">
            <h1 className="endgame-heading">Leaderboard</h1>
            <div className="endgame-leaderboard">
            {leaderboard.map((data)=>{
                return(
                    <div key={data.name} className="user-container">
                        <p className="username">{data.name}</p>
                        <p className="userdata">{data.time}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            </div>
            <button className="endgame-button" onClick={startGameClick} >Start Game</button>
            </div>
            )}

        </div>
    )
}

export default EndGame
```

So I have this endgame component and when it renders for some reasons the setScore function gets called and i think thats why i get a error of this:

Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but Leaderboard has 1.

On line 27. Am i in the wrong here thinking its beacause of setScore gets called on render? If not what the problem/solution?

In firebase i have a Leaderboard collection inside that i want to create docs from users time and name, (each users should have 1 doc)

Answer (score 0):

Method `addDoc` should have a collection reference not a document reference. You'd only use a document reference if you want to specify a document name into it and it should use `setDoc` instead, see sample code below:

```
   const setScore= async(timeprop, userprop)=>{
        console.log(time, user)
        await setDoc(doc(db, "Leaderboard", "<document-name>"), {
        name: userprop,
        time: timeprop,
      })
    }
```

To correct this, check out the sample code below:

```
   const setScore= async(timeprop, userprop)=>{
        console.log(time, user)
        await addDoc(collection(db, "Leaderboard"), {
        name: userprop,
        time: timeprop,
      })
    }
```

You may want to checkout this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) for more information.